# how to show other ad services when admob doesn`t have ads?

Tags: android, admob, ads

Most of my users are in Iran and according to the problems between Iran and USA sometimes people don't want to show their ads in Iran, so sometimes AdMob doesn't have any ad for Iranian users. I'm using Admob for my tv application so the user has to see an ad then can use the app. There is another service just like AdMob in Iran and it just shows the ads from Iran. How can I add it to my project? I mean I wanna use AdMob always and just when AdMob doesn't show up, users see the other service. Should I use the OnFailure method? does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, so the problem you are facing is already solved by the mediation.

Mediation is nothing but a bunch of ad networks integrated with a fashion that if one fails then you can always go for another one. So you can define the order of the ad networks and based on that it will start from the top of the list and keep checking with each network, whenever any network provides an ad then that will be shown otherwise it will keep iterating through the list.

There are already such mediations available like MoPub, DFP, AerSerc etc. Check whichever works in Iran.